# Formatting entity in json format does'nt show in view

Tags: json, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is the view, the success function should make changes in the `<p id="mondiv"></p>`tags.

```
<input type="button" value="Refuser" class="refuser" id="{{ demande.id }}">
<p id="mondiv"></p>

        <script>
            $(".refuser").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ path('verifier_demandes') }}',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {'id_demande': this.id},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data,function (i,e) {
                            $('#mondiv').append('<ul>'  
                                +'<li>'+e.id+'</li>'
                                +'<li>'+e.etat+'</li>'
                                +'<li>'+e.user.nom+'</li>'
                                +'<li>'+e.user.prenom+'</li>'
                                +'<li>'+e.user.username+'</li>'
                                +'</ul>');
                        })
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                })
                }
            );
```

This is the controller, the entity gets deleted like intended but since then i can't change my view element ( the success function )

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {
            if ($request->get('id_demande')) {
                $id_gerant = $request->get('id_demande');
                $gerant = new Gerant();
                $gerant = $em->getRepository("GestionBoutiquesBundle:Gerant")->findOneBy(array('id' => $id_gerant));
                $em->remove($gerant);
                $em->flush();

                $demandes = new Gerant();
                $demandes=$em->getRepository('GestionBoutiquesBundle:Gerant')->findBy(array('etat'=>false));

                $ser= new Serializer(array(new ObjectNormalizer()));
                $data=$ser->normalize($demandes);
                return new JsonResponse($data);

            }
        }
```

I have looked from both sides, the controller sending back the Json response, and from the view, but couldn't find any result.

**EDIT:** knowing that the $demandes i'm trying to send back with Json is an array of users, each user has an id, etat, nom, prenom, username..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a POST request so you should be able to access to the post data as follow:

```
            $id_gerant = $request->request->get('id_demande');
            if($id_gerant) {
            ....
```

instead of:

```
        if ($request->get('id_demande')) {
            $id_gerant = $request->get('id_demande');
            ....
```

As described here in the doc [Symfony Request Object](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object)

Hope this help

Comment: No, i have no problem accessing the data sent to the controller, i was able to define the problem which is in formatting ( serializing and encoding ) the entity in json format to send it back to the view, can't figure out the exact problem.

Comment: I fixed it, i had to add an $.each function in the $.each function,
`success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $.each(data,function (i,e) {
                            $.each(e, function (j,e2) {
                                $('#mondiv').append('<ul>'
                                    +'<li>'+e2.id+'</li>'
                                    +'<li>'+e2.etat+'</li>'
                                    +'</ul>');
                            })

                        })
                    }`